# Group and take count by expanding values in column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I wish to groupby and then create column headers with the values in a specific column and list their counts.

### Data

```
location    box     type    
ny          box11   hey 
ny          box11   hey 
ny          box13   hello   
ny          box13   hello   
ny          box13   hello   
ca          box5    hi  
ca          box8    hello
```

### Desired

```
location    hey hello   hi
ny          2   3       0
ca          0   1       1
```

### Doing

using crosstab as SO member assisted w this script.

first group, then crosstab

```
df1 = df.groupby(["location", "box"]).agg()

df2 = pd.crosstab([df["location"], df["box"]], df["type"])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated- still researching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need `box`

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df["location"], df["type"])
Out[271]: 
type      hello  hey  hi
location                
ca            1    0   1
ny            3    2   0
```